# Ruby rspec mocking a class with an attribute that is a hash

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, hash, rspec

I have a class I am testing, call it myfoo.  It accesses a class called yourbar.  Specifically something like this...

```
yourbar_obj.projects[project_name]
```

In my spec code I have this

```
let(:yourbar_obj) { Class.new }
```

and I want to mock it to respond to the hash attribute access.
So I tried this

```
expect(yourbar_obj).to receive(projects).and_return(some_obj)
```

But when I run the code it says

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `projects' ...
```

Is it possible to mock a hash access like that?  The same type of thing works for regular method calls.
I even tried adding a .with(project_name) just in case.  Same error.
thoughts?

Comment: use `receive(:projects)` - you pass the method name as a symbol. this has nothing to do with hash specifically, it's always like this with `receive`

Comment: Also the `with(project_name)` doesn't make sense here either. If you wanted to mock the `[project_name]` getter call you'd use `expect(projects).to receive(:[]).with(project_name).and_return(whatever)`

Comment: whoa.  How did I miss that.

Comment: Okay, it didn't like just :projects... got an undefined method on [].  So I added that like this. `with(projects[])`   That got me a wrong number of arguments error.

Comment: If you could show the "undefined method on []" you receive as well as your exact attempt it would be useful, but anyway, `with(projects[])` is wrong, why do you put the `[]` at the end there?

Comment: I put the [] in there cause it said it was undefined... and that made it go away. :)   But the solution just hit me.  I was returning the object I expected the hash to contain at that key.  But what I needed to return was a hash that it could then use to lookup the key.  I will fill in that answer below.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Max's help.  Here is the correct answer...

```
some_hash_obj[project_name] = some_obj
expect(yourbar_obj).to receive(:projects).and_return(some_hash_obj)
```

Two key parts.  The : before projects, and some_hash_obj must be a hash.  I was trying to return the value (which was an obj) at the hash index in one shot, but that ain't how it works.  return the hash, and the [] will apply to it.